# Back to mainland Norway from Svalbard

Tags: schengen, norway, danish-residents

I have a residence permit of Denmark. I will visit Svalbard and then go from Svalbard to Copenhagen. Since I will need to transit in Oslo and Tromsø, and Svalbard is outside of the Schengen area, I am not 100% sure if I can enter mainland Norway from Svalbard using my danish residence permit. Any help is appreciated:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your valid unexpired EU common format residence permit from Denmark allows you to enter any other Schengen area countries for 90 days out of every 180 days. You can travel confidently.

Comment: Thanks! I've been back from Svalbard. Everything goes smoothly:-)